# List property doesn't bind on post in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I know this question has been asked a zillion time but pardon me as I have wasted quite a number  of hours now, thus finally posting it. 
So to summarize I have a a view Model having some complex type prperties and a complex type list property .

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Gains = new List<Gain>();

    }
    [UIHint("Common")]
    public AllRegRecordsLog commonRegisterFields { get; set; }
    public Potential Potential { get; set; }
    [UIHint("Gains")]
    public List<Gain> Gains { get; set; }

    public void CreateGains(int count = 1)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            Gains.Add(new Gain());

        }


    }

}
```

now my view createOrEdit I call this property as ,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gains)
```

I have placed an editor template inside my specific view folder

```
@model Gains
    table id="gainsTable" class="content-tables"style="width:98%">
    <tr id="defaultGainsRow">
            <td class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VolumeGainLow)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VolumeGainLow)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VolumeGainLow)
            </td>

            </tr>

     <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <input id="addGainsButton"type="button" class="t-button" Value="Add Potential Gains"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

But somehow I get the error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List  but expects Gains"

I am using asp.Net MVC 4

Please point me in right direction.

Thanks

Bilal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for assistance guys I solvex it using the following post

http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the editortemplate to take a List and also perform the looping logic inside that

```
@model List<Gain>
@foreach(var gain in Model)
{
    table id="gainsTable" class="content-tables"style="width:98%">
    <tr id="defaultGainsRow">
            <td class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(gain=> gain.VolumeGainLow)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(gain=> gain.VolumeGainLow)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(gain=> gain.VolumeGainLow)
            </td>

            </tr>

     <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <input id="addGainsButton"type="button" class="t-button" Value="Add Potential Gains"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
}
```

EDIT: my razor might not be 100% but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks Daniel tried this but then after post the list property binds as null. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to declare your view as bound to a property instead of to a type.  This is not possible.  You have to declare the model as a valid type that is referenced by your web project in order for templating to work.

The type of the `Gains` property is `List<Gain`>`.  Since your`Gains`view has a`Gains`type declared, your`UIHintAttribute` is invalid.